# C#: Require indexer on method parameter

Tags: c#

I'm writing a function which is a mapper from one type of object to another. The object which is passed in as a parameter of the Map method should have a string indexer to find the appropriate value in the object (or not). I don't really care if the mapper gets a Dictionary, DataRow, DataReader, etc.

Is there a way to specificy that the parameter passed to the method should implement a string indexer? I can't find anything like it.

I'll use reflection to cast the type to something usable if it's not possible, but I was wondering if there is proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do that.  You could use an interface like Andrew's, or you could pass in a `Func<T, string>` that retrieves an indexed value.

```
public void ConsumeIndexedFunction<T>(Func<string, T> something)
{
    var foo = something("bar");
    // do something with foo
}

public void TestMethod(
    Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary,
    DataTable myDataTable,
    IDataReader myDataReader)
{
    ConsumeIndexedFunction(x => myDictionary[x]);
    ConsumeIndexedFunction(x => myDataTable.Rows[0][x]);
    ConsumeIndexedFunction(x => myDataReader[x]);
}
```

(Credit to Michael Meadows for fleshing out this idea into an example.  Thanks!)

Comment: Thanks. The interface won't fix it since I can't add an interface to predefined classes like DataRow / Dictionary. I guess the typed idea is probably the nicest way to solve this!

Answer (score 5):

You can create an interface like this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    String this[Int32 index] { get; set; }
}
```

All types that implement this interface will have to implement a string indexer and if the type of the parameter to your method is `IFoo` you can know that it will have an indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can make all objects (or classes respectively) you like to pass to the mapper implement an interface which defines such an indexer, you will need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Would an Interface not help in this case:

```
interface IImplementMe {
    string this[int index]
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Just require that the parameter implements the Interface